# Multiple Must in elasticsearch query using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to query data using the new c# api. I do know the field values and would simply like to retrieve the correct record(s).
E.g.

```
// client is an instance of ElasticsearchClient

var response = await client.SearchAsync<EffectSerie>(s => s
    .Index(_indexName)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(sd => sd
                .Term(t => t.startDate, "2023-11-01")
                .Term(t => t.endDate, "2023-11-02")
                .Term(t => t.periodType, 4)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This will however get all records with the matching periodType. I'm using the newest version of Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch and not Nest.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @val each term should be met.

Comment: I guess with startDate and endDate you should use `range` queries, it's more appropriate to match dates than term ones

Comment: @Val Thanks, the dates actually work, however the int periodType seem to get all records with that matching value

Comment: @EricHerlitz To clarify the question **This will however get all records with the matching periodType.**, do you mean it's matching all records regardless of startdate match or not. If so can you share your `index mapping`?

Comment: @MusabDogan Yes, it will retrieve all records with the matching periodType regardless of other matches. It acts as an `OR` query.

Comment: All the clauses in the *must* query must be satisfied... So it must be`AND` logic. IF you can share a couple of documents and the mapping I can check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this, it turns out that the params on the Must selector could also be an array. So the proper way to do this was to segment the lambda a bit.

```
var response = await client.SearchAsync<EffectSerie>(s => s
    .Index(_indexName)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(
                mu1 => mu1
                .Range(r => r
                    .DateRange(dr => dr
                        .Field("startDate").Gte(startDate).TimeZone("-01:00:00")
                        .Field("endDate").Lt(endDate).TimeZone("-01:00:00")
                        )
                ),
                mu2 => mu2
                .Term(t => t.periodType, periodType)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This will form a working query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "endDate": {
              "gte": "2023-11-05",
              "lt": "2023-11-06",
              "time_zone": "-01:00:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "periodType": {
              "value": 4
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```